# Mapping cells between between two ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a couple ranges of data for which I need to map the values in one range to the values in the other range. I'm probably explaining this terribly, so here's an example below:

I have a range with standardized residuals (Range1):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.7 | 0.6 | -3.6 |  |
| -1.5 | -0.8 | 3.6 |  |
| -0.2 | 0.2 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

And a second set of standardized residuals (Range2)

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2.6 | 1.7 | 0.7 |  |
| 1.5 | -0.7 | -0.7 |  |
| 1.2 | -1.2 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

I take a bootstrapped sample from Range1 and get this output (BS1).

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.6 | -3.6 | -1.5 | 3.6 |
| -0.2 | 0.6 | -0.2 |  |
| -0.2 | -3.6 |  |  |
| 1.7 |  |  |  |

Now I want to use BS1 to get to get a bootstrapped sample of Range2 (BS2) by using the location of each BS1 value in Range1.

For example. BS1(1,1) = 0.6. That corresponds to Range1(1,2). So, BS2(1,1) = Range2(1,2) = 1.7. I want to end up with this table, BS2.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.7 | 0.7 | 1.5 | -0.7 |
| 1.2 | 1.7 | 1.2 |  |
| 1.2 | 0.7 |  |  |
| -2.6 |  |  |  |

Can anyone think of ways to accomplish this using Excel formulas? I can't use VBA for this. As unlikely as it sounds, neither Range1 nor Range2 will have duplicate values, so I'm hoping that simplifies things a bit.

**Edit: I'm limited to Excel 2016 functions as well. Sorry, I should have mentioned that before.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can convert the two ranges to columns using Tocol, then use xlookup to locate the matching cells:

```
=IF(BStrap1="","",XLOOKUP(BStrap1,TOCOL(Range1,1),TOCOL(Range2,1)))
```

[image]

I have changed BS1 to Bstrap1 because BS1 isn't a valid range name (looks like a cell reference).

---

In Excel 2016, you could do it with a formula which you copy down and across, so if the top left hand cell of your BS1 is in A9 say, you would have:

```
=IF(A9="","",SUM((Range1=A9)*Range2))
```

using the fact that there are no dups in Range1 and Range2 and also assuming that the ranges are defined with $ signs like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm limited to Excel 2016 so I don't have those functions.

Comment: I will add a suggestion to my answer - it's just a formula which you can copy down/across.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(B4:H10<>"",B14:H20,"")
```

[image: Sample illustration]